# how to get public ip through by gprs modem

Tags: modem, gprs

I am using wavecom gsm gprs modem

Model No: M1306B

How to we enable the public for this modems.

We doinged from the followings.

```
AT+WOPEN=1
OK
AT+CGREG=1
OK
AT+CGAAT=1
AT#APNSERV="AIRTELGPRS.com"
ERROR

AT#APNSERV="CELLONEPORT"
ERROR

AT+CONNECTIONSTART
ERROR.
```

What can we do the settings.

Please advise me.

Comment: I suggest you remove your personal contact details, and keep this on-site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get your internet ip, you have essentially two options:

1) DIY - Determine the correct strategy to retrieve this data from your OS.

2) Phone a friend - Set up a server somewhere on the internet with a small server that will, when connected to, tell you your IP address. This would be little more than a few lines of code (and I expect such a thing exists already).